# sequelize - how to calculate the value of a column based on the value in other table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

There are 2 tables which are `users` and `tutorial`.

The relationship:

```
users(1) : tutorial(Many)
```

The `users` table has below column

```
    completeOneOfTheTutorial: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      ...
    },
```

which is true when

```
    isCompleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
```

is `true` in one of the tutorials.

If `isCompleted` is `false` for all tutorials of the same user, `completeOneOfTheTutorial` will be `false`

**Example**
User table

```
  [
     {
        id: "user1",
        completeOneOfTheTutorial: true
     }
     ,
     {
        id: "user2",
        completeOneOfTheTutorial: false
     },    
  ]
```

tutorial table

```
  [
     {
        id: "tutorial1",
        userId: "user1",
        isCompleted: true
     }
     ,
     {
        id: "tutorial2",
        userId: "user1",
        isCompleted: false
     },   
     {
        id: "tutorial1",
        userId: "user2",
        isCompleted: false
     }
     ,
     {
        id: "tutorial2",
        userId: "user2",
        isCompleted: false
     },   
  ]
```

How should I modify this field in `users.model.js`

```
    completeOneOfTheTutorial: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      ...
    },
```

users.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const users = sequelizeClient.define('users', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    },
    completeOneOfTheTutorial: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      ...
    },
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  users.associate = function (models) {
    users.hasMany(models.tutorial,{
      foreignKey: 'userId'
    });
  };

  return users;
};
```

tutorial.model.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const DataTypes = Sequelize.DataTypes;

module.exports = function (app) {
  const sequelizeClient = app.get('sequelizeClient');
  const tutorial = sequelizeClient.define('tutorial', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    isCompleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  }, {
    hooks: {
      beforeCount(options) {
        options.raw = true;
      }
    }
  });

  tutorial.associate = function (models) {
    tutorial.belongsTo(models.users);
  };

  return tutorial;
};
```